# Only Samsung Android Camera Intent returns data null in landscape mode

Tags: android, camera, landscape

I am using a Samsung Android System camera to capture images, in that I got null image data in onActivityResult while it was captured in landscape mode but works well in portrait mode.

Note: The orientation of the Activity I used is Portrait.

Code:

```
private void openCameraIntent() {
    boolean hasGps = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    if (hasGps) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolvedIntentActivities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(takePictureIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.vcs.ecp.provider",
                        photoFile);
                for (ResolveInfo resolvedIntentInfo : resolvedIntentActivities) {
                    String packageName = resolvedIntentInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    grantUriPermission(packageName, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Crouton.makeText(DoctorVisit.this, getString(R.string.device_unsupported), Style.ALERT).show();
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String dateInString = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = User_NAME + "_" + intDrGlcode + "_" + dateInString + "_" + randomNo;
    File storageDir = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null && !mCurrentPhotoPath.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
              ArrayList<String> photoPaths = new ArrayList<>();
              photoPaths.add(mCurrentPhotoPath);
              manageFileSize(photoPaths);
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Here Intent data & mCurrentPhotoPath both are blank in landscape mode.

Comment: `both are blank in landscape mode.` ? Please elaborate as you said earlier `Note: The orientation of the Activity I used is Portrait.|`

Comment: The system camera is in both modes. My app is in portrait mode.

Comment: Expierienced about  the same with all devices while rotating. That mCurrentPhotoPath is reset is because your activity was killed while the camera app was on top of it. Quite normal. Use onSaveInstanceState to save that variable. What i saw was that getContex() (in a fragment) delivered null after rotating.